# Apache: Serve content from files that are restricted

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

In my Apache setup, I have a directory with my error pages in it (404 403). However, I don't want this directory being viewable directly - I'd like accessing it to return a 404. So what I did was this:

```
# Use /hidden/404/ as the 404 page
ErrorDocument 404 /hidden/404/
# Use /hidden/403/ as the 403 page
ErrorDocument 403 /hidden/403/
<Directory /path/to/root/hidden/>
    # All requests return 404
    RedirectMatch 404 .*
</Directory>
```

the problem is that Apache seems to be unwilling to serve the files at *all* in this case, even when I tell it to explicitly (that is, to handle 404 and 403 errors). In fact, when I visit `/hidden`, I get the following message:

```
The requested URL /hidden/404/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an 
ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Any way I can tell Apache to disallow access to the directory while still allowing itself to serve those files when necessary?

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out a way to do it.

What I did was use `mod_rewrite`, which is an Apache module (shipped by default with all installations) for rewriting requested URLs on the fly. Here's the code:

```
# Custom error pages
ErrorDocument 404 /hidden/404/index.html
ErrorDocument 403 /hidden/403/index.html

# Pretend that /hidden doesn't exist
# (unless this is an internal redirect,
# such as rendering a 404 or 403)
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
RewriteRule ^/hidden/.* - [L,R=404]
```

So let's walk through these lines. The `ErrorDocument` directives haven't changed - they just say what page should be served when a given error occurs.

The real meat is in the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` directives. What the `RewriteRule` directive says is this: if a url is requested whose path matches the regex `^/hidden/.*` (essentially, any path that is to anything in /hidden/ or its subtree), leave the url unchanged (that's what the `-` means), but don't interpret any more `RewriteRule` directives (that's what the `L` means), and return a 404 error code (that's what the `R=404` means).

This, combined with the `ErrorDocument 404 /hidden/404/index.html` directive, might seem to do the trick. The problem, however, is that when Apache goes to serve `/hidden/404/index.html`, it runs through these rules again. That means that the `RewriteRule` directive is executed, which in turn says to render the 404, and the whole thing just infinite-loops.

Thus, we use the `RewriteCond` directive to make sure this doesn't happen. `RewriteCond` directives are conditionals - the `RewriteRule` directive below will only be executed if the condition is satisfied. The condition in this case is "the environment variable `REDIRECT_STATUS` is equal to the empty string." Now, `REDIRECT_STATUS` is an environment variable that is set by `ErrorDocument`, and holds the status code that is being redirected (so, if the `ErrorDocument 404 ...` directive had been triggered, it would be set to the value "404"). However, if no `ErrorDocument` directive had been executed, then `REDIRECT_STATUS` would not have been set, and so asking for its value would simply return the empty string. Thus, `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""` essentially says, "don't bother evaluating the `RewriteRule` directive below unless we're not in the middle of serving an error page."

---

**note:** if you have looked at the `RewriteRule` documentation, you may have noticed that the `R` argument is supposed to perform an explicit redirect. The reason it works fine in this case is that there's an undocumented feature of the `R` argument which is that it only redirects on 300-class codes. Thus, `R=404` does not do an explicit redirect, only an internal one.