# How to deny direct access to ErrorDocument in Apache httpd

Tags: apache-2.4, configuration, apache2

Suppose I have a simple directory structure like the following:

```
/var/www/html
  - index.html
  - 404.html
```

And a simple configuration like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName example.com
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I prevent direct access to 404.html, i.e. when someone tries to access `http://example.com/404.html` directly, return a status code of 404 NOT FOUND, plus the content of 404.html?

Right now, if I access the URL directly, it will return 200 OK. If I tries to modify the status code via `mod_rewrite`:

```
<Location /404.html>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]
</Location>
```

then an actual 404, e.g. `http://example.com/not-exist.html`, will return the following error:

> The requested URL /not-exist.html was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

So, how can I hide the 404.html from visitors, but still use it as the custom 404 error page?

Answer (score 1):

After looking at [a similar situation](https://serverfault.com/a/618777/320744), I found the solution to this problem - there's a variable named `REDIRECT_STATUS`<sup>[[ref](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html#variables)]</sup> that will be set by apache when apache looks up the ErrorDocument internally.

So using the variable, I can add a new rewrite condition to allow apache to exclude actual 404 from being rewritten:

```
<Location /404.html>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
    RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]
</Location>
```

and it solved my issue.